# How can I use matlab diag command for ultidyn inputs?

Tags: matlab

Dears

I've try to define Diagonal Input Multiplicative  Uncertainty using diag command but I got below error.

*Check for missing argument or incorrect argument data type in call to function 'diag'.*

Here is my code:

```
R=ultidyn('r');
S=ultidyn('s');
T=ultidyn('t');
DiagBlock= diag([R,S,T]);
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: diag returns the dragonal of a square matrix or returns a diagonal matrix when provided an input vector.  What are the dimensions of R, S and T? I suspect they aren't even vectors or matrices, but rather objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears

I've used below matrix instead of diag command and solve my problem.Maybe helpful for you.

```
DiagBlock= [R 0 0;0 S 0;0 0 T]
```

Best wishes